# Evaluate the limit: $ \lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x\ln(x+3) + \ln(2)} {x+1} $

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x\ln(x+3) + \ln(2)} {x+1} $$

I tried to separate the fraction and also a change of variable (x+3 = y+1) but I couldn't solve it. Maybe there's a trivial step that I'm just missing. Thanks.

Note: the person I was trying to help doesn't know how to use l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Thanks "user26486" and "lab bhattacharjee" for your quick answers. I was shooting for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ln(x+1)} {x} = 1$ that's why I couldn't get the change of variable right. It wasn't that hard after all. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a `limits-without-lhospital` tag! >.<

Answer (score 3):

Set $x+1=y$ to get

$$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{(y-1)\ln(y+2)+\ln2}y=\lim_{y\to0}\ln(y+2)-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(y+2)-\ln2}y$$

Now,
$$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(y+2)-\ln2}y=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac y2\right)}{\dfrac y2}\cdot\dfrac12=?$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x\ln(x+3)$.

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x\ln(x+3) + \ln(2)} {x+1}=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x-(-1)}=f'(-1)$$